# Jackson with Builder Pattern

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've seen many questions around using jackson to serialize/deserialize java objects using builder patter, however, I can't figure out why this code below won't work. I'm using Jackson version 2.5.4

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = User.Builder.class)
public class User {

    private String name;

    private User(Builder builder) {
        this.name=builder.name;
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build")
    public static class Builder {
        private String name;

        public Builder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new Learner(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to output the string representation always prints an empty list {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `@JsonPOJOBuilder`expects the builder methods to starts with `with` prefix. 
You should override this in the annotation: `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")`

You should also mark the `name` field with the `@JsonProperty` annotation, or add a getter, or use the [JacksonFeatureAutoDetect](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureAutoDetect) feature; otherwise Jackson does not see `name` as a JSON property.

Comment: still returns an empty list.

Comment: I'm doing it in Play framework, which basically is Json.toJson(object), but I've also tried it using ObjectMapper. Something like this..

        User user = new User.Builder().name("raunak").build();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);

        System.out.println(s);

Comment: OK. You see the empty object when serialize it to JSON because the name property does not have a JsonProperty annotation or a getter. This is not directly related to the builder annotation  which concerns the deserialization.

Comment: aah, I see. The JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="") is required for deserialization. As for serialization, any property I want to output, I should either place @JsonProperty in front of the property, or create a getter method. Tested and worked. Thanks